# Unity2D: Instantiated Object always at wrong position

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I've got an GameObject called "PlayerList" and inside this is a "PlayerListItem", which I Instantiate and clone inside the PlayerList, the code for that looks like this:

```
private void CreatePlayerList()
        {
            int y = 0;
            foreach (var player in gameState.PlayerNames)
            {
                GameObject PlayerName = Instantiate(playerListItem, new Vector3(0, y), Quaternion.identity, playerList.transform);
                PlayerName.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text = player.FirstName;
                PlayerObjects.Add(PlayerName);
                y -= 130;

                if (player.FirstName == gameState.PlayerNames[currentPlayer].FirstName)
                {
                    UpdatePlayerStates();
                }
            }
            // Destroying the first empty item
            Destroy(playerListItem);
        }
```

Now my problem is, that the cloned items are always at a complete wrong position, than I actually instantiate them. The first item (second actually since I delete the first one because its empty) always has the X/Y Positions: -420 (x) and -573 (y)

The weird thing is that the -130 y is always used after that, so the next item has the same X Position and -703 as Y-Position.

It appears this is a problem of the vector3 function, since when I removed it, all items just had 0,0 as Position. Am I using the Vector3 Function incorrectly?

The Rect Transform of my GameObjects looks like this by the way:

[image: PlayerList]

[image]

And also the PlayerListItem is a child of the PlayerList:

[image: structure]

Thanks for anyone who helps!

Comment: In the second iteration of your loop. Y is -130. So yes. Unless it’s the first item. That’s where it will be spawned

Comment: I believe that the question here is: why is the second item at `(-420,-573)` and not `(0,-130)`?

Comment: Exactly. I want the second item to be at 0, -130 and every other item at 0, y-130

Comment: Should new Vector3(0, y) be new Vector2(0, y)? Also, maybe you have an issue with children and relative positions. Are any of your objects children of any others?

Comment: @pseudoabdul vector2 does the exact same thing. And yeah the PlayerListItem is a child of PlayerList I'll update my initial post about that!

Comment: Do you want worldspace or local space? Try setting "instantiateInWorldSpace" true in parameters? Or instantiate and then set position.

Comment: You try instantiate to 0,0 and later setposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the position of the elements after instantiating them. It's also a good idea to set `worldPositionStays` to false when parenting UI elements.

```
var obj = Instantiate(prefab, Root, worldPositionStays: false);
```

You may also need to use `anchoredPosition` instead of `position`.

```
((RectTransform)obj.transform).anchoredPosition = new Vector2(x,y);
```